# incrementation goes haywire when performed in `setState` callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a code in which `state` should be incremented by 1 every 2 seconds. `setState` is called inside `setInterval` callback, but instead of using a typical form of `setState`: `setState(newState)` I used a callback form `setState(() => {...})` and weird things started happening. Instead of incrementing by 1, the state is being incremented by 2.

Here's the simplification of the offending code:

```
const handler = () => {
   let val = 0;
   setInterval(() => {
      setState(() => {
        console.log("before inc", { val });
        val = val + 1;
        console.log("after inc\n--------", { val });
        return val;
      });
    }, 2000);
}
```

The expected logs would be:

```
before inc {val: 0}
after inc {val: 1}
-------- 
before inc {val: 1}
after inc {val: 2}
--------
```

but instead I've got:

```
before inc{val: 0}
after inc {val: 1}
-------- 
before inc {val: 2}
after inc {val: 3}
--------
```

which is super weird. What is happening?

Playground: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sparkling-shape-fshi8?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: You have [`<React.StrictMode>`](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) enabled in `index.js`.

Comment: I really don't get why this was closed as a duplicate... This is not a duplicate of that question, it is related but not a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this happens because your `App` is wrapped with `<React.StrictMode>`. [Strict Mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) renders twice your component in development to find any issues, which may cause some side effects like that.

If you remove the wrapping `<React.StrictMode>` tag your component will render once and your code will work as expected.

Comment: in strict mode React calls a function passed to `setState` twice, hence the incrementation is doubled but why I don't see console.logs from these additional calls?

Comment: okay, I found the answer in the docs: "Starting with React 17, React automatically modifies the console methods like console.log() to silence the logs in the second call to lifecycle functions.". That's weird.